# Get Information from HTML using Selenium

Tags: html, r, selenium, docker

I am trying to extract some text from an amazon website with R. Probably because amazon uses a ajax technique, it is not possible to extract the data with xml_attrs() directly.

```
library(rvest) 
library(RSelenium)
Produktlink<-'https://www.amazon.de/AmazonBasics-CW190423-Mikrofaser-Reinigungst%C3%BCcher-24-St%C3%BCck/dp/B009FUF6DM/ref=zg_bs_automotive_10/262-2805299-5636062?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=TK56QZCA9CH997338J1B'
Name<-xml_attrs(xml_child(xml_child(xml_child(xml_child(xml_child(xml_child(xml_child(xml_child(xml_child(xml_child(read_html(pageSource), 2), 1), 46), 8), 8), 3), 1), 1), 1), 1))[["class"]]
```

Thats why I think I need Docker and Selenium:

```
remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100", port = 4445L)
remDr$open(silent = T)

remDr$navigate(Produktlink)
```

But I wasnt able to find for example the product name searching with:

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "class", "a-size-large")
webElem$getElementAttribute("name")
```

Can anyone help me or does anyone know an other way to extract text from the website?

Best regards

Comment: Why didn't you look for the element by id (`<span id="productTitle">`). And have you tried `webElem$getElementAttribute("html")` or `webElem$getElementText`

Comment: My results are still empty lists, I didnt find the text with this method too. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you require RSelenium. I found the product title as follows:

```
library(rvest) 
library(xml2)
library(stringr)

Produktlink <- 'https://www.amazon.de/AmazonBasics-CW190423-Mikrofaser-Reinigungst%C3%BCcher-24-St%C3%BCck/dp/B009FUF6DM/ref=zg_bs_automotive_10/262-2805299-5636062?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=TK56QZCA9CH997338J1B'

html <- read_html(Produktlink)

html %>%
  xml2::xml_find_all("//span[@id = 'productTitle']") %>%
  xml_text %>%
  str_replace_all('\n','') %>%
  trimws()
```

result:

```
[1] "AmazonBasics Mikrofaser-Reinigungstücher, 24 Stück"
```